# How to logout with jquery or just javascript using form authentication?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm using forms authentication in my web application. Is there any way to logout (FormsAuthentication.SignOut;) using jQuery library or javascript?

Comment: Just think of ajax like any other page request, except it is done without a redirect or a hidden iframe.

Answer (score 2):

You could request that with XHR, except you will need to update your page to reflect the new state.

Comment: By far the best answer here.  Thank you for explaining it so elegantly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will need to create a controller action, if you're using MVC or a generic handler if you're using WebForms. This handler/action will need to call the `FormsAuthentication.SignOut` method. In jQuery you will need to make an ajax call to this action/handler.

```
$.post('/url/of/signout/action', null, function(data) {
   //handle successful logout
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You have to send an ajax request to the server.  Look at ajax in the jquery documentation.  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/